# Proper way to make a react native app for iPad and tablets with landscape mode only

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ios-simulator, landscape

I'm new to react development and recently started a project that is only available for iPad and tablet devices and the app should only work on landscape mode. How should I do that in react? In iOS I tried to change the settings to device iPad only and then disabled the portrait mode, so, if I build from Xcode it does seems to scale the app for iPad but if I run it through `react-native run-ios` command it does build the app in iPad but it seems to build like a universal build with both iPhone and iPad support, i.e you have the option to scale to iPhone also. What should be the proper way to proceed, so that my app only build for iPad or tablet devices and in landscape mode regardless of any environment I choose to build?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your app work just in `Landscape` mode you can do this :

**For IOS :**

Step 1 : open `Info.plist` file from your iOS folder and removing (better to comment it) this line:

```
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
```

From both UISupportedInterfacePortrait and UISupportedInterfacePortrait~ipad keys.

**For Android :**

Open the file android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Then add `android:screenOrientation=”landscape”` to the activity as seen at line 23 of the code below :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.applificationhq.orientation"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="1.1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />    
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That’s all. Next time you run your app it will stay in landscape regardless of device orientation.

GoodLuck

Comment: This will make it landscape only but if I run it on iPad it still shows a scalable version of iPhone. I tried changing on Xcode to make it iPad only but only works if I build through Xcode. If I run through the command line its still builds for iPhone app on iPad.

Comment: he is talking about scaling app in ipad devices

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/41373